# wp_list_table put table header and table content that does not belong from the database

Tags: php, wordpress, html-table

I'm having hard time with this. I know `WP_List_Table` will generate the table for you and the `get_columns` will set the `header` and `footer` of the table that came from an array well in most case that came from the database.

What if I have this database table and it's fields

```
+----------------+
| Field |  Type  |
+-------+--------+
| id    | int    |
+-------+--------+
| name  | varchar|
+-------+--------+
```

Then in my `get_columns` function.

```
function get_columns() {
  $columns = array(
           'id' => 'ID',
           'name' => 'Name'
           );
  return $columns;
}
```

So with that.. It'll give me html table like this..

```
+--------------------+
| ID    |  Name      |
+-------+------------+
| 1     |  Foo       |
+-------+------------+
| 2     |  Bar       |
+-------+------------+
```

BUT (1) how can I add another header and footer that does not belong in the database? I would want to achieve something like this..

```
+--------------------+--------+
| ID    |  Name      | Option |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 1     |  Foo       | Click  |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 2     |  Bar       | Click  |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

(2) I would also want to wrap the `Click` text in a `<form>` so I can do some actions with it. I don't know how to deal with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This post might be helpful - OP solved your issues in his question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278772/extending-wp-list-table-handling-checkbox-options-in-plugin-administration

Comment: Thanks for the link. But how can I add those additional header and content without having them in the database?

Comment: What happens if you add something like `'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />'` to your `get_columns()` array definition?

Comment: Thanks dude! Last question, but how can I wrap it in a `<form></form>` ?? Because I want to do something with it.

Comment: Just posted as an answer to your question. I think you may want to open a new question regarding what exactly you want to do with the `Click` and `<form></form>` stuff. (What actions are you trying to accomplish? Provide code of what you've tried so far. etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the field to your `get_columns()` function like this:

```
function get_columns() {
  $columns = array(
           'id' => 'ID',
           'name' => 'Name',
           'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />'
           );
  return $columns;
}
```

The `cb` column is actually a special case and it automatically creates a "select all" checkbox in your table header. Form functionality is built in so, depending on what you want to do, you'd create some actions by overwriting `get_bulk_actions()` function. More information on this can be found here: http://wpengineer.com/2426/